# Stargazer in R : Summary statistics by group

Tags: r, statistics, summary, stargazer

I have a panel data with TOT firms, in which variables are analyzed for 11 years.
Do you know a "special" STARGAZER code which permit to have a descriptive statistics of the variables for each year? I already got summary statistics of the whole sample, but I need it for each year.
Thank you in advance.

I tried:

```
stargazer(subset(data[c("Var1","Var2","Var3"), data$YEAR], 
                 type="text" , title="Summary Statistics" , 
                 out="samplesummary.html")
```

But it doesn't work.